# Change the dbPath for Mongodb

Tags: linux, mongodb

I'm having trouble changing the dbPath of MongoDB on my development machine.

I used the [install instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) found on the MongoDB site. I have installed MongoDB 3.4.0-rc2 on to Linux Mint 18, my development machine.

My `/` partition is relatively small and I would like MongoDB to store the DB files in my much larger `/home` partition. In `/etc/mongod.conf` I have changed dbPath to `dbPath: /home/mongodb/data`

The permissions are fine and if I start mongod using
`mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf`
everything works as expected.

If I don't specify the config file I get the following error

```
exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
```

When trying to start the service nothing seems to happen, and from what I can tell, no logs are created.

While reading through the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath) I found the following

> The Linux package init scripts do not expect storage.dbPath to change from the defaults. If you use the Linux packages and change storage.dbPath, you will have to use your own init scripts and disable the built-in scripts.

How do I disable the built in scripts, where are they? Or am I doing all this wrong?

Comment: Hi , could you achieve changing dbpath ?

Answer (score 0):

The error

`exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating`

just because the default `storage.dbPath` is `/data/db` on Linux and OS X, you can find it on https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath .

The built in scripts on `/etc/init.d/mongod`, if you want to disable it, just remove it.